# How to call httppost method from Login.cshtml having different layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, layout, html.beginform

In MVC project I want to add the following layout to my login.cshtml

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
```

I added the above line to login.cshtml page and supplied the credentials and click login this causes the page to call Get Login method of account controller instead of HttpPost Login method. Removing the above line calls the HttpPost Login method. Please guide me is there something I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is it the issue with the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my mistake I was unintentionally creating two forms one in

```
Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })
```

and another  tag in my _LoginLayout.cshtml

I removed the one from layout and everything was working like a charm

If any one can contribute to explain this please help for the future users.